# How to create a multiple path from several BezierPath

Tags: arrays, swift, uibezierpath, cashapelayer, bezier

I'm working with swift 2.2 and I'm dealing with such problem:
I have an array of UIBezier objects and I need to create a stroke for them as one path.

I used to have a special function for that, but the pros of that approach, that it created several layers. 
That goes along with my requirements, as I need one layer

```
 func createStroke(line: UIBezierPath) {

        self.currentPath = CAShapeLayer()
        currentPath.path = line.CGPath
        currentPath.strokeColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
        currentPath.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
        currentPath.lineWidth = 1
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(currentPath)

    }
```

What is the best way to create a multiple path from an array of my Bezier lines? The first idea is to create a for-loop cycle, but I consider it is not a clean way.

Comment: You can create a single path by appending all bezier paths, then set the result as the CAShapeLayer path. More info: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uibezierpath/1624377-append

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do something like this (this is playground code):

```
let myView = UIView(frame:CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 250, height: 250))
myView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
let myLayer = CAShapeLayer()

func createPath(i: Int) -> UIBezierPath {
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 2*i, y: 9*i - 4))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 10 + 5*i, y: 20 + 4*i))

    return path
}

func createStroke(line: UIBezierPath) {
    myLayer.path = line.cgPath
    myLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    myLayer.fillColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    myLayer.lineWidth = 1
}

let paths = [createPath(i: 0), createPath(i: 15), createPath(i: 8), createPath(i: 10)]
let myPath = UIBezierPath()
for path in paths {
    myPath.append(path) // THIS IS THE IMPORTANT PART
}
createStroke(line: myPath)
myView.layer.addSublayer(myLayer)

myView
```

here is what it looks like in playground:

[image: playground exemple]

You will only have one layer this way

Comment: Thanks for providing playground-ready code!